# Cron не запускает скрипт

Tags: python, bash, cron

Есть небольшой python скрипт, с шабангом в начале

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Скрипт отлично запускается через bash, но вот такие строчки не срабатывают в `crontab -e`

```
* * * * * /home/user/script/script.py > /home/user/script/log
* * * * * python3 /home/user/script/script.py > /home/user/script/log
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/user/script/script.py > /home/user/script/log
```

Кроме того, в логе ничего не появляется. syslog рапортует о выполнении команды:

> Apr 10 10:58:01 boss-K55DR CRON[4098]: (user) CMD (python3 /home/boss/.backgrounds/bg_changer.py > /home/boss/.backgrounds/bg)

Как заставить cron выполнять скрипт?

Comment: в сторону: 1- stderr следует перенаправить, чтобы ошибки видеть в log файле. Добавьте `2>&1` в конце. 2- Установленные скрипты, должны фиксированный адрес в shebang использовать, например: `/usr/bin/python3`. See [Should I put #! (shebang) in Python scripts, and what form should it take?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31954823/4279)

Comment: @jfs Добавить `2>&1` в конце чего? Что делает эта последовательность? Точнее, что значит `&1`?

Comment: `> /.../log 2>&1` это синтаксис перенаправления. 1, 2 это file descriptors для stdout,  stderr потоков соответственно (кстати, shell в cron также может отличаться, если вы явно `SHELL=/bin/bash` не указали. В баш проще перенаправить оба потока в один файл: `/.../script &> /.../file`

Comment: @jfs я просто всегда думал, что достаточно `2>1`, амперсанд нужен для получения адреса объекта, по аналогии с Си?

Comment: Если интересно как и почему `2>1` от `2>&1` в  shell отличаются, то задайте отдельный вопрос—это и другим может полезно (или существующий уже вопрос посмотрите).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение было найдено на англоязычном stackoverflow.
Проблема в том, что cron'у доступен лишь ограниченный набор переменных окружения, а для выполнения bash-скрипта (в моём случае камнем преткновения послужил демон gsetting, именно к нему должен был обращаться скрипт) нужна переменная окружения `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`
Для этого импортируем её:

```
PID=$(pgrep gnome-session)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-)
```

Подробнее:

[1] https://askubuntu.com/questions/140305/cron-not-able-to-succesfully-change-background

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374520/gsettings-with-cron